# After adding bootstrap modal the nav link stopped working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I had stuck in one part of my code which sounds strange but its happening with me that on using bootstrap modal the nav links its not working !!

Can you check my code of modal why its happening ??

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" style="text-decoration:none">QUICK ENQUIRY</a>

<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog">

  <!-- Modal content-->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
      <h1 class="modal-title"><center>Have A Questions?</center></h1>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <form id="modal_contact" action="include/process.php"  method="POST">

        Full Name  : <input type="text" name="name" class="name" placeholder="Full Name"><br>
        Email Id :&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="text" name="email" class="email" placeholder="Email address"><br>
        Phone No : <input type="text" name="phone" class="email" placeholder="Phone no"><br>
        Website : &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="text" name="website" class="email" placeholder="Your Website"><br>
         Questions : <input type="text" name="question" class="email" placeholder="Your Question??">
        <center><input type="submit" name="contact"  value="Send Message"></center>
      </form>
    </div>

  </div>

</div>
</div>
```

```html
 

<div class="nav-collapse collapse">
  <ul class="nav">
    <li>
      <a id="home-nav" href="index.php" style="text-decoration:none" onMouseOver="this.style.color='#8348ac'" onMouseOut="this.style.color='#7281a1'">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a id="home-nav" href="thank-you.php" style="text-decoration:none" onMouseOver="this.style.color='#8348ac'" onMouseOut="this.style.color='#7281a1'">Services</a>
      <ul class="dropdown">
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="search-engine-optimization.php" style="text-decoration:none" onMouseOver="this.style.color='#8348ac'" onMouseOut="this.style.color='#7281a1'"> Search Engine Optimization</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="on-page-optimization.php" style="text-decoration:none" onMouseOver="this.style.color='#8348ac'" onMouseOut="this.style.color='#7281a1'">On Page Optimization</a></li>
            <li><a href="Off-Page-Optimization.php" style="text-decoration:none" onMouseOver="this.style.color='#8348ac'" onMouseOut="this.style.color='#7281a1'">Off Page Optimization</a></li>
            <li><a href="Social-Media-Optimization.php" style="text-decoration:none" onMouseOver="this.style.color='#8348ac'" onMouseOut="this.style.color='#7281a1'">Social Media Optimization</a></li>
            <li><a href="Content Marketing.php" style="text-decoration:none" onMouseOver="this.style.color='#8348ac'" onMouseOut="this.style.color='#7281a1'">Content Marketing (Keyword Based)</a></li>
            <li><a href="SEO-Reporting-Structure.php" style="text-decoration:none" onMouseOver="this.style.color='#8348ac'" onMouseOut="this.style.color='#7281a1'">Reporting Structure</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="website-designing-and-development.php"style="text-decoration:none" onMouseOver="this.style.color='#8348ac'" onMouseOut="this.style.color='#7281a1'">Website Design and development</a></li>
        <li><a href="email-marketing.php" style="text-decoration:none" onMouseOver="this.style.color='#8348ac'" onMouseOut="this.style.color='#7281a1'">Email Marketing</a></li>
        <li><a href="mobile-responsive-website.php" style="text-decoration:none" onMouseOver="this.style.color='#8348ac'" onMouseOut="this.style.color='#7281a1'">Mobile Responsive Website</a></li>
        <li><a href="pay-per-click-advertisement.php" style="text-decoration:none" onMouseOver="this.style.color='#8348ac'" onMouseOut="this.style.color='#7281a1'">Pay Per Click</a></li>
        <li><a href="ecommerce-deveopment.php" style="text-decoration:none" onMouseOver="this.style.color='#8348ac'" onMouseOut="this.style.color='#7281a1'">Ecommerce Development</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a id="blog-nav" href="#" style="text-decoration:none" onMouseOver="this.style.color='#8348ac'" onMouseOut="this.style.color='#7281a1'">About Us</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div id="pks"><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" style="text-decoration:none">QUICK ENQUIRY</a></div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Thanks !!!

Comment: What nav link is not working, please include all relevant code

Comment: The code snippet works fine on my end, can you include the part of your code where your nav links are located?

Comment: Please check the updated code!!!

Comment: What is happening here is once i open a bootstrap modal then all links works fine!

Comment: @PiyushSeofaceup Please put the code into the same snippet and make sure the snippet demonstrates your problem

Comment: On putting in one its not working!! means no result is displaying!!

Comment: I got the problem its because of the form i used inside the modal Once i removed the form now everything works fine @CarstenLøvboAndersen